# Combine two Dictionaries

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, addition

I'm learning Swift and can't find the solution for my problem...

I have two Dictionaries and want to combine them:

```
dict1 = ["A": 1, "B": 2, "D": 5]
dict2 = ["A": 3, "C": 9, "D": 4]
```

The outcome should be a new Dictionary like:

```
dict3 = ["A": 4, "B": 2, "C": 9, "D": 9]
```

Comment: It's [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_(programming_language)), not [SWIFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_Worldwide_Interbank_Financial_Telecommunication)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Dictionary `merging` method and pass the plus sign (addition operator) as the `uniquingKeysWith` parameter:

```
let dict3 = dict1.merging(dict2, uniquingKeysWith: +)  // ["A": 4, "B": 2, "D": 9, "C": 9]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

The answer is so simple i wasn't able to find it xD

Comment: If it helped, you could mark this as answer.